# MDX LastPeriods for Rolling Count Null values

Tags: mdx, ssas-2012

I have created a calculated member in my cube to figure out the event count for a 12 month rolling period. I have a measure called `Event Count` I have used the `LastPeriods` function to do this. However, I am having a problem when I have a month that has not got any data,  my Measure [Event Count] is showing null and my calculated member shows null as well - I really need the 12 month rolling count to continue, replacing the  Null for a 0 in the count so I would get a value for the month if I got a 0.

So if jan event Count was 5 and Feb was `Null` I should still all the previous 11 months worth of data added together with so the rolling count would still be 5

I have the following MDX as my calculated member and I still get nulls. I have tried doing a CASE statement as well.

```
IIF (isEmpty([Measures].[Event Count]) , 
Sum(LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember),0),
Sum(LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Event Count])
```

has anyone came across this problem before or can see where I am going wrong

Comment: Have you try to use the Aggregate function instead of Sum?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you explicitly state in your expression that the result should be zero and not the event count if the current period has no event count, as then you sum `0` and not the event count measure. hence, the formula should be

```
Sum(LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Event Count])
```

without the `IIf(IsEmpty())`.
You could then set the value to zero after summing, by nesting the result into `CoalesceEmpty()`, i. e.

```
CoalesceEmpty(
  Sum(
    LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[Event Count]
  ),
  0
)
```

Secondly, the formula as stated only works correctly for months. For quarters, it would sum 12 quarters, and for years it would sum twelve years. Instead of using `LastPeriods`, I would suggest using `ParallelPeriod` to go back one year, independent of the level of teh period hierarchy on which you are, and then from there go one member forward to get the start period of the sum, i. e. use the following formula:

```
CoalesceEmpty(
  Sum(
    ParallelPeriod(
      [Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].[Year Name],
      1,
      [Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember
    ).NextMember
    :
    [Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember,
    [Measures].[Event Count]
  ),
  0
)
```

Please note that the colon operator creates a range of members beginning with its left operand and ending with its right operand.

Comment: Thanks for your input - Yes, I understand that the formula should only be `Sum(LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Event Count])`. However, I have tried the CoalesceEmpty and I am still getting NULL values in my rolling count and have tried your other suggestion and I still get the NULLS . My year on my date dimension is `[Year Name]` any other suggestions to why I am getting NULLS. I was under the impression that as I am using `SUM` that all NULLS would be treated as 0's

Comment: @GavinCampbell Sorry, I forgot the second argument for `CoalesceEmpty`, a `0`. And I adapted the year hierarchy name. Nulls are treated like 0 in numeric context in most cases. This does not apply to the case of nothing being there, but something being there and having the value `null`.

Comment: yeah I noticed that and fixed it in my calculated member still having the issue of NULLS appearing though

Comment: What I would do then would be running queries using some measures defined from intermediate expressions to determine how far everything works and where it breaks. Examples for measure expressions in the `WITH` clause of a query would be `[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember.Name`, `SetToStr(LastPeriods(12,[Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember))`, or `(ParallelPeriod(
      [Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].[Year Name],
      1,
      [Event Date].[CalendarYQMD].CurrentMember
    ).NextMember,  [Measures].[Event Count])`.

Comment: I have got to the bottom of it. in the cube for the Calculated Measure I have turned off the NON-EMPTY behaviour , which not set it to any measure. So

`NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Event Count] }`,  is now `NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR =`

Comment: @GavinCampbell As far as I am aware (but I do not remember a reference), Microsoft discourages the use of NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR from version 2008 except for some few cases where it may improve performance.